# Failed to install Magnolia Data Module (version 2.3.0)

Tags: java, magnolia

I've imported `magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit` maven dependency in Pom file in webapp. It's version is 2.3.0 and Magnolia version is 5.3. After build & run Tomcat server and start install modules, I encountered a failure as below:

```
Magnolia Data Module (version 2.3.0)
Could not install or update data module. Task 'Data AppLauncher group ordering' failed. (PathNotFoundException: /modules/ui-admincentral/config/appLauncherLayout/groups/data)
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<!-- Overlay Magnolia Empty Webapp. Alternatively, use the bundled-webapp or the enterprise-webapp. Dependencies versions are already imported by parent, so no need to replicate here. -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-empty-webapp</artifactId>
  <type>war</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.projects</groupId>
  <artifactId>myTemplateModule</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia.contacts</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-contacts</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
  <artifactId>magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Anyone can help me resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to replicate the exception you get and i think the problem is the order you add the dependencies and do the "Start install" process.

if i first do a "Start install" with only the magnolia-empty-webapp dependencies and then i stop the server, add the magnolia-module-standard-templating-kit to the pom.xml and do another "Start install" i got the exception:
[image: data module exception]

But if instead i do a "Start install" specifying all the dependencies (stk and empty-webapp) from the beginning i don't get an exception at all
[image: no exception]

I recommend you to add these dependencies as well for demo project and the pop theme

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
     <artifactId>magnolia-theme-pop</artifactId>
     <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>info.magnolia</groupId>
    <artifactId>magnolia-demo-project</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, Diego. But it does not work :(. I also added Magnolia core into pom file as your suggest but still encounter the same error.

Comment: no problem Ha Doan, i managed to replicate the error and edited the answer with a new solution, i hope it can help you otherwise let me know.